# Use external property in struts.xml

Tags: java, properties, jboss, struts

I have a config.properties located in my Jboss conf folder.

**config.properties**:

```
server.url=http://localhost:8085/
```

I would like to use this properties in my **struts.xml** :

```
    ...
    <action name="logoutAction" class="app.LogoutAction">
         <result name="ok" type="httpheader">
          <param name="status">301</param>
          <param name="headers.location">server.url</param>
         </result>
    </action>
    ...
```

Is it possible ?

Or is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, no.

The best bet would be to use a [dynamic result](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/result-configuration.html#dynamic-results). You'd need to fetch that value somehow during startup, or at runtime, and fill it in from the action. You may not need to retrieve the value from the config, though, it might be available in requests--don't recall.